# How to use a pattern when doing for loop of files in directory

Tags: bash, find, regular-expression, inotify

I'm a novice bash scripter.  Need help with the following.  I have a script that uses inotifywait to watch a directory.  Another process will drop a csv file in nightly.  The file will be of the format **filename_YYYYMMDD.csv**.  My script takes the oldest timestamped file and renames it **filename.csv**, so it's ready to be consumed by another external process.  In a perfect world, one files comes in, gets renamed without timestamp, and is processed.  The external process moves the file to an archived folder.
If the external process is down, the timestamped files will accumulate in the folder.  My script renames the first file when it hits the directory, but the rest will go untouched until that first file is archived.  Then my script finds the oldest file, renames it, and exits.

When the timestamped file first hits the directory, my script checks for a timestamp in the name:

```
regex='_[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}(.csv)$'
if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
```

This works fine.  I check for a file already existing named **filename.csv**.  If none, this file gets renamed.

When a file is processed and archived, the script detects that file is gone, gets the basename and looks for the next oldest file matching that basename, renames it, and exits.

Finally, here's where I need help.  How can I modify the below code to look for the oldest file matching a pattern?  If I just look for basename, I pick up a malformed filename, like **filename_YYMM**, which I don't want.

```
unset -v oldest
for f in $mybasename*; do
   [[ -z $oldest || $f -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$f
done
```

Right now $mybasename is just **filename**.  How can I get the for to use a regex like:

```
regex='$mybasename_[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}(.csv)$'
for f in $regex; do
   [[ -z $oldest || $f -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$f
done
```

Thanks!

Comment: zsh has built-in functionality to find oldest/newest files matching a pattern; is that an option for you?

Comment: You're doing this the hard way! Use a soft link (`man ln`) to point to the file to process (`ln -s filename_YYMMDD.csv filename.csv`), use `stat` (`man stat`) output the filename and other data, sort `man sort`, `cut` off (`man cut`) the other data, and move the link along (delete and re-create the link).

Comment: i'll look at zsh and soft links. thanks

Comment: Why do you need to rename it?  Why not just process it and move it to another directory (the archive dir)?

Comment: An external process is predefined to read a static filename, which doesn't include the timestamp.

Comment: I'd use a symlink instead of renaming the file.  that way you get to keep the date in the filename in the archive dir.